# iOS7: Control center, remote-control, and CoreAudio audio session solo-ambient category

Tags: ios7, core-audio, remote-control, control-center

Before iOS7 came, we noticed an issue:
Music `remote-control` from earbud or springboard can hijack our audio session even if we set the category to `solo-ambient` or another exclusive mode.

We thus tried a few things:

1. We tried to take ownership of the audio session back. But this requires that our audio code knows when to take it back and from whom. We thought we could let the app code become the first responder to remote-control events, do our stuff, and then pass the events on to the music app. However, we found that the events got detained by the first responder and there is no way to push it back to the chain of commands.
2. We tried to become first-resonder and block remote-control events all together when we are in `solo-ambient`. This worked fine with iOS6, still works with earbud control in iOS7, but fails with iOS7's `control center`. The `control center` seems to bypass the `remote-control` event handler `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` completely, where we put our blocking code.

I read something elsewhere that:

> You can't block the music app. your app can become one though (apple
>   won't like that) and then the control center would control yours.

But I found no documentation whatsoever about `control center`.
And as said above, control center does not enter the normal remote control hooks even if an app is the first responder.

Another quoteP

> Remote Control Event handling is so your app can be controlled by
>   Control Center, the earbuds, etc... it is not so that your app can eat
>   said controls, preventing control of other apps from said sources. It
>   only worked in iOS6 because of a bug in iOS, now fixed in iOS7

Is it that what had were using was due this bug? I find it hard to believe because we got the solution on this list and the Xcode mailing list so I assume that was an accepted solution.

Now we really wonder if we are missing something from the very beginning:

Is `solo-ambient` really an exclusive mode for audio session or is it that music app is an exception to that exclusivity?

How can our app live in harmony with the `remote-control`, and `control center`?

Where can we find up-to-date documentation of `remote-control` and `control center`?

Answer (score 0):

The remote control has been mysteriously fixed after clean building everything agains iOS7 SDK. Now app delegate can receive remote-control events from Control Center. However, the play/pause events are UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause and UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay instead of the iOS6's UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause.